# Byte string to long value

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, arrays

Byte string to long value:

I have a string of Hex values, as in '*,ff,fe,d0,ea*', how do I convert these to a (big-endian) long value? Code snippet:

```
dataStr = ',ff,fe,d0,ea'
dataVal = struct.unpack('>l', '\xff\xfe\xd0\xea')[0]
print dataStr, ' = ', dataVal      # prints out ,ff,fe,d0,ea  =  -77590
```

I think `\` is an unprintable char, so I believe my question is really (given the snippet), how do I convert from `,ff,fe,d0,ea` to `\xff\xfe\xd0\xea`? or any array values suitable for the `struct.unpack` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will decode `',ff,fe,d0,ea'` to `'\xff\xfe\xd0\xea'`

```
dataStr = ',ff,fe,d0,ea'.replace(',', r'\x').decode('string-escape')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line that will do the conversion to to a hex string suitable for unpacking.

```
hexstr = "".join([chr(int(ss, 16)) for ss in dataStr.split(",") if ss])
```

Often when you have hex strings like this what you really want is an unsigned integer. So, to get that with unpack you do this:

```
myval = struct.unpack(">I", hexstr)[0]
```

Now you have 4294889706 as the result.

But in the first line you already had integers, so you could also shift and them yourself. Here's how you can do that.

```
res = 0
for v in [int(ss, 16) for ss in dataStr.split(",") if ss]:
   res <<= 8
   res += v
```

Gets the same result.